# What is the Yoga shastra of Dattatreya?

Tags: yoga, dattatreya

Dattatreya, who is said to be avatar of Tridev, was born in 10th Treta yuga of the current Vaivasvara Manvantra and is believed to have acquired the knowledge of Yoga. In his history, there was no Guru for him but he rather attained the enlightened state by observing 5 elements of nature (Panchabootha), people etc.

Recently I heard he has prescribed yoga shastra for Moksha. Do any of scriptures describe it?

Comment: May be the Dattatreya Tantram?

Comment: I don't know @Rickross... that's why asked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the Jivanmukti-Gita consisting of 23 slokas explaining the meaning of Yoga and Mukti by Sri Dattatreya.

Please check the link : https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_giitaa/jivanmuktigiitaa.html?lang=iast

The Yoga-Sastra by Dattatreya can be purchased here: https://www.exoticindiaart.com/m/book/details/yoga-sastra-of-dattatreya-rare-book-NAD535/

Comment: Your answer is fine to some extent on Jivan Mukti Gita. But Do you know Dattatreya tantram which @Rickross mentioned?

Comment: @AkshayS No i have not heard of such tantra

Comment: Dattatreya Tantram is there .. Few Bengali publishers have published it too .. Also see this: https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/dattatreya-tantra-with-hindi-translation-khemraj-edition-NZA877/ @Partha

Comment: But the Q asks about Yoga Shastra of Dattatreya and u hv given the link for it besides giving another Yogic text related to him .. so this is a good answer. @Partha

Comment: @Rickross Can you answer that Tantram?

Comment: I can not because I don't have the book I only know that such a book exists @AkshayS I think this answer is good enough isn't it?

Comment: @Rickross This answer is fine but elobrated answer would be better!!!

Comment: Ok but that i am unable to do that :) you can wait for more answers @AkshayS

Comment: @Rickross thanks Rickross for this new information. I had never heard of it:)